# C# Regex: match capture groups multiple times

Tags: c#, regex

I need help to match text as follows:

Example inputs:

```
[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test%") And ([Table1].Name.Contains("%Test2%") Or [Table1].Name.Contains("%Test3%"))
([Table1].Name.Contains("%Test%") Or [Table1].Name.Contains("%Test2%")) And [Table1].Name.Contains("%Test3%")
```

The different parts between the "And" and "Or" should be considered as the main text to be identified, and all other text such as parentheses should be ignored. I have 3 identifiable string I would like to parse in this example, but there could be none, or many more, and they could be enclosed in multiple or no parentheses.

So in the examples above I would need to identify 3 strings:

```
[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test%")
[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test2%")
[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test3%")
```

Regex so far:

```
^(?<replace>(?<column>.*?)(?:\.Contains\("(?<like>.*?)"\)))(.*)$
```

So far I can only capture the first string until the "And" but I would also like to capture to two last strings. I have been looking into positive/negative lookahead/lookbehind but I can't nail it.

Match information from https://regex101.com/

```
Match 1
Full match  0-107   `[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test%") And [Table1].Name.Contains("%Test2%") Or [Table1].Name.Contains("%Test3%")`
Group `replace` 0-32    `[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test%")`
Group `column`  0-13    `[Table1].Name`
Group `like`    24-30   `%Test%`
Group 4.    32-107  ` And [Table1].Name.Contains("%Test2%") Or [Table1].Name.Contains("%Test3%")`
```

For the input above, I would like to have 3 "replace" groups, 3 "column" groups and 3 "like" groups if that is possible.

So for output I would like 3 matches with each 3 groups, so:
Match 1, would have replace="[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test%")", column="[Table1].Name" and replace="%Test%"
Match 2, would have replace="[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test2%")", column="[Table1].Name" and replace="%Test2%"
Match 3, would have replace="[Table1].Name.Contains("%Test3%")", column="[Table1].Name" and replace="%Test3%"

Comment: Please give us an example of the output so we can have a better understanding of what you need

Comment: Perhaps without use the anchor `^` you could use `(?<replace>(?<column>\[[^]]+\]\.\w+)\.Contains\("(?<like>%[^%]+\%)"\))(?: And | Or |$)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VRfCj7/1/)

Comment: Added example of expected output - hope that clarifies it.

Comment: You do not need regex : string[] matches = input.Split(new string[] { "And", "Or" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToArray();

Comment: I see what you mean, but if it can be solved with a single Regex, that would be preferable.

Comment: @mfas Does my suggestion work for you?

Comment: @Thefourthbird That is like splitting on And/Or, right? Kinda the same as jdweng proposes.

Comment: @mfas But I think splitting on And/Or would not give you the groups replace, column and like.

Comment: I have edited the question again, to be more specific in my needs.

Comment: You might make the parenthesis optional but note that that would also match unbalanced parenthesis. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ospwWj/1/)

Comment: @Thefourthbird You may post an answer. It was close enough to what I needed, so you solved it. My final regex was this: \(*(?<replace>(?<column>\[[^]]+\]\.\w+)\.Contains\("(?<like>.*?)"\))\)*(?: And | Or |$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, for the first posted example data, you could omit the anchor `^` and use the 3 capturing groups:

`(?<replace>(?<column>\[[^]]+\]\.\w+)\.Contains\("(?<like>%[^%]+\%)"\))(?: And | Or |$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VRfCj7/1/)

**Explanation**

- `(?<replace>` Start group `replace`

  - `(?<column>` Start group `column`

    - `\[[^]]+\]` Match opening `[`, 1+ times not closing `]` and then closing `]`
    - `\.\w+` Match a dot and 1+ word characters
  - `)` Closing group `column`
  - `\.Contains\("` Match `.contains("`
  - `(?<like>)` Start group `like`

    - `%[^%]+\%` Match `%`, 1+ times not `%` and then %`
  - `)` Close group `like`
  - `"\)` Match `")`
- `)` Close group `replace`
- `(?: And | Or |$)` Alternation which matches either `And`, `Or` or the end of the string